# Point estimate and 95% credible interval

Tags: prior, point-estimation, credible-interval

The text of the problem as follows:

The data follows a normal distribution with
$\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ unknown. We wish to perform inference on the mean selling price $\mu$.

And our sample data are (212,249,250,240,210,234,195,199,222,213,233,251)

(a) Suppose we assume an $IG(1100,250000)$ prior for $\sigma^2$ and let the prior for $\mu|\sigma^2$ be
$$p(\mu|\sigma^2)\propto (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}exp^{-\frac{(\mu-\delta)^2}{2\sigma^2/s_{0}}}$$
with $s_{0}=1$ and $\delta=220$. Find a point estimate and 95% credible interval for $\mu$.

(b) Suppose now that we had assumed the independent improper priors
$$p(\mu)=1, -\infty<\mu<\infty$$
$$p(\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma}, 0<\sigma<\infty$$
Find a point estimate and 95% credible interval for $\mu$.

In (a), I can calculate that $p(\mu|\sigma^2)$ follows a normal distribution. Then I want to use Monte Carlo method to sample from $p(\sigma^2)$ and $p(\mu|\sigma^2)$. Is it correct?

In (b), because the prior is improper, I cannot sample from the prior distribution of $\sigma^2$. How to calculate the credible interval?